# Layout handle for onepage checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, magento-1

I want to have a specific CSS file at the onepage checkout and I was simply wondering if there is a layout handle for that (so I don't have to make one).

**Probably answered my own question, but I found this in my search: http://itpscan.info/blog/magento/layout_handles.php**

Might come in handy for other people searching for default XML handles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the one page check out index  handler

`<checkout_onepage_index>`

By default you this is the handler you can find this handler in layout folders `checkout.xml` file

I think you know the xml code for adding the css if you not then tell me I will update the code

Comment: Ok and if its help You then mark as accepted when you done the work

Comment: OK Try and If its Help to you then only accept.

Comment: Haha, that was not what I meant :p When you post a question, you have to wait like 12 minutes before you can accept an answer.

Comment: Ok Bro, I dont know about that, Sorry

Answer (score 1):

Rather than changing directly in checkout.xml it is good if you create local.xml in your layout folder and add your xml code there as it is the best practice to make your custom changes separately.

Below will be the code in your local.xml

```
<layout version="0.1.0"> 
    <checkout_onepage_index translate="label">
        <reference name="head"> 
            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/yourstyle.css</stylesheet></action>
        </reference>
    </checkout_onepage_index>    
</layout>
```

Comment: I know the standard procedure of making use of the fallback system, but good that you mentioned it for people who don't know this yet! :)